# ¿Cómo filtrar valores de un dataFrame a partir de valores de columna de otro dataFrame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

Tengo dos dataframe:

```
d1= 
    cod   M1   M2   M3
0  231.0  1.0  1.0  2.0
1  345.0  3.0  3.0  1.0
2  678.0  2.0  2.0  1.0
3  592.0  2.0  1.0  1.0
4  357.0  3.0  1.0  2.0

d2=
   cod  consul
0  231.0  8902.0
1  345.0  8902.0
2  611.0  8902.0
3  592.0  8902.0
4  598.0  8902.0
```

Requiero crear una salida de datos con las filas de d1 que cumplen con la condición de que el valor de la columna cod esta en el dataframe d2.

Para mi ejemplo la salida de datos sería:

```
salida= 
    cod   M1   M2   M3
0  231.0  1.0  1.0  2.0
1  345.0  3.0  3.0  1.0
2  592.0  2.0  1.0  1.0
```

He intentado utilizar la siguiente instrucción sin éxito (sale vacía):

```
filtro = d1[d1.cod.isin(d2)]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

El error está en que a `pandas.Series.isin` le pasas el DataFrame `d2` completo mediante su argumento `values`, no la columna `d2.cod` por lo que en la practica estás comparando los valores de la serie con las filas del DataFrame, por lo que la máscara booleana es `False` en toda su extensión como cabe esperar.

```
>>> import io
>>> import pandas as pd

>>> data1 = io.StringIO(
''' cod   M1   M2   M3
0  231.0  1.0  1.0  2.0
1  345.0  3.0  3.0  1.0
2  678.0  2.0  2.0  1.0
3  592.0  2.0  1.0  1.0
4  357.0  3.0  1.0  2.0
''')

>>> data2 = io.StringIO(
'''cod  consul
0  231.0  8902.0
1  345.0  8902.0
2  611.0  8902.0
3  592.0  8902.0
4  598.0  8902.0
''')

>>> d1 = pd.read_table(data1, sep='\s+')
>>> d2 = pd.read_table(data2, sep='\s+')

>>> filtro = d1[d1.cod.isin(d2.cod)]         # <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

>>> filtro
     cod   M1   M2   M3
0  231.0  1.0  1.0  2.0
1  345.0  3.0  3.0  1.0
3  592.0  2.0  1.0  1.0
```

Comment: Muchas gracias.